# Angular2 - how do I add a loading spinner?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm pretty new to Angular 2, I have a site created which calls services but need to add a loading gif for each page or service call. Does anyone know how I can implement something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

On your HTML you can write a spinner like the following:

```
<span *ngIf="isLoading">Loading...</span>
<span *ngIf="!isLoading">Result</span>
```

Before loading the service, probably on component load, you will have something like this on your component:

```
isLoading: Boolean = true;
```

Call the service on that component, subscribe to it, then change that boolean to true after the subscription has completed.

```
myService.subscribe(
  result => {
     // your other stuff here.
     isLoading = false;
  },
  error => {
     isLoading = false;
  }
```